# Defining a ExpressJS route from a Typescript class

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm trying to load `ExpressJS` routes from a Typescript class. The idea is that this should eventually be dynamic routes. But I'm already stuck at defininghard coded routes in a class.

My `index.ts` js looks like this:

```
import generic = require('./generic');
import Generic = generic.Generic;

class Test {

  private app:any;
  private port:number = 3000;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    new Generic();
    this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
      console.log('Listening on port ' + this.port);
    });
  }
}

export = Test;
new Test();
```

Then my `generic.ts` looks like this. I'm trying to define another route from this class:

```
module Generic {
  export class Generic {

    constructor() {
      console.log('In generic');

      var router:any = express.Router();

      router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(200).send("AAA");
      });
    }
  }
}
export = Generic;
```

When I run my application then I see the message ***In generic*** appear in console. But when I load my browser it says:

```
Cannot GET /
```

So for some reason it's not really registering the route from the `Generic` class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [sample on Microsoft's github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/imageboard). Rather than using `express.Router`, they simply use `get` and import the function from an external module. It has worked pretty well for me.

app.ts

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as routes from "./routes/index";

var app = express();

app.get('/', routes.index);
```

routes/index.ts

```
import express = require("express")

export function index(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'ImageBoard'});
};
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, they are asking about classes

Comment: agreed, I am also looking for a class-based approach